# Segmentation fault in strlen when using FTS fts_open()

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, traversal, strlen

I have a bug that I've found boils down to this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fts.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
    char *LOG_ROOT = "/var/log";

    FTS *ftsp; 
    FTSENT *p, *chp;
    int fts_options = FTS_COMFOLLOW | FTS_LOGICAL | FTS_NOCHDIR;

    char *paths[] = { LOG_ROOT };
    fts_open(paths, fts_options, NULL);
}
```

Why does this segfault?

Comment: Added the all-too-relevant "array" tag to this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first arg. is expected to be a **NULL terminated array** of character pointers.

```
char *paths[] = { LOG_ROOT, NULL};
```

Comment: You are my absolute hero right now. I've been staring at 1000 lines of code for 2 hours trying to find the problem. Commenting out random lines fixed the problem because they would leave that location NULL.